# Installing Windows software "SET" by Trend for Building Control

Tags: wine

I am running into a problem when I try to install this IQ Set program from Trend microcontrollers.
It is to scan and manage building control systems.
My aim is to eventually install this on a Raspberry Pi, so I don't want to run Windows, and ideally, I won't have to at all after first run.

I have installed Wine, and Wine com loader, so the .Net stuff is there, that worked ok.
However when I try to install the SET program, it "experiences an internal error" and doesn't fully install it.

Some of the errors appear to be
wine64-preloader crashed with SIGSEGV
backtrace stopped, Cannot access memory at address xxx

Can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Software development is done differently on Linux than on Windows. In general, Linux comes with powerful command line tools that integrate well with automation tools such as build systems and CI (continuous integration).

If you feel you need to install some Windows software for this, chances are that you are heading down a wrong path. Maybe let us know what you intend to do; then the community here will very likely be able to point you to a Linux tool that can do the same thing, and probably better.

Comment: unfortunately the user wanting this tool isn't me. I am wanting to use a Raspberry Pi ultimately for the BMS, but the BMS people are only familiar with Windows, and don't have a supportive software from Trend to connect to the panel - which probably runs Linux, but they can't connect, and neither can I.
They only know how to use this WIndows Software :(